# modify underlying result/value of async object

Tags: java, kotlin

I am using Kotlin in a webserver app and I have a line of code as follows:

```
.onComplete { jsonResult: AsyncResult<JsonObject>? ->
```

Now what I want to do is change the underlying JsonObject wrapped in the `AsyncResult`, so that it is going to be reflected further downstream.

```
var res: JsonObject? = jsonResult?.result()
if (res != null) {
    if (res.getInteger("files_uploaded") > 0) {
            res.put("URL", "Some URL")
    }
}
```

I was then imagining to update the underlying JSON object in the result but not sure how to do that.

Comment: What is `AsyncResult`? It is not part of Java or Kotlin stdlib.

Answer (score 0):

*please take note that single quotes are missing and ` appear as \` because the code formatting.  I tried to leave what seemed least confusing...*

You should be able to make changes in the conditional statement

```
if (res !=null) {
```

res being the JsonObject:

```
console.log(res);
```

would show you what's in there.  You may need to use

```
let resXmodifiedX = JSON.parse(res);
```

> One approach is to write a function and pass res to that function which you can do if it is in the console.log(res).

Some notes on what's below:

- place the function somewhere consistent maybe at the bottom of the file...
- objects often have multiple levels res.person.name, res.contact.email, or whatever...

  - use multiple for loops:

  let level = res[key];  for(child in level) {

  - you don't need to do this if you know exactly what object attributes you need to update.
- you can set the value directly but you always want to test for it before trying to set it to avoid errors that stop execution.

  let toBe = toBe =>`${toBe}`;

  let update = (res)?toBe(update(res)):toBe('not Found');

This option is really only if you know for sure that data will be there and you can't proceed without it.  Which is not uncommon but also not how JSON is designed to be used.

> The code below is a concise way to make some simple changes but may not be an ideal solution.  To use it xModify(res) replaces console.log(res) above.

```
function xModify(x) { 
  let resXmodifiedX = JSON.parse(x);
  let res = resXmodifiedX;
  for (key in res) {
  res[key] = key=='name'? \`My change ${res[key]}\`: key=='other'? \`My Change ${res[key]}\`:res[key];
  resXmodifiedX = JSON.stringify(res);
  return resXmodifiedX;
}
```

> That will update res.name and res.other otherwise res[key] is unchanged. If you do not need to parse res change let res = xModifiedx; to let res = x; remove the first line and change the last two lines to return res;

```
function xModify(x) { 
  let res = x;
  for (key in res) {
  res[key] = key=='name'? \`My change ${res[key]}\`: key=='other'? \`My Change ${res[key]}\`:res[key];
  return res;
}
```

If your data is numeric which is not generally the case in a web server response scenario this is a terrible approach.  Because it is probably a string I used the template variable as a way to easily add a complex pattern in place of a string.  `My change ${res[key]}` not a real world example.  Any valid JS code can go in the ${ } (template variable). I've been defaulting to the first pattern more and more.

```
let me = (bestCase)?`${'the best version'} of myself`:`${'someone'} I'm ok with`;
```

Comment: The question is about Kotlin, not JS ...